# Bypassing overriding actions in controllers

Tags: php, ajax, magento, controller

I've installed a few new modules, ajaxcartpro and saveforlater. Saveforlater calls an addAction() action in it's controller. The addAction from mage_checkout_controller is being overridden by the one in the ajaxcartpro module.

I was wondering if there's a way to specifically use the addAction action from mage_checkout_controller instead of the one from ajaxcartpro.

Saveforlater controller calling addAction():

```
public function moveAction(){
    $saveforlater_item_id = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('item');
    if( $saveforlater_item_id ){
        $saveforlater_item = Mage::getModel('saveforlater/item')->load( $saveforlater_item_id );
        $buy_request = unserialize( $saveforlater_item->getBuyRequest() );
        $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
        $this->getRequest()->setParams( $buy_request );
        $this->addAction();
        $saveforlater_item->delete();
    }
}
```

Is there a way I can change the line $this->addAction(); to specifically call addAction from mage_checkout_controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. If your class extends `Mage_Checkout_CartController`, you can call it via `parent`:

```
parent::addAction();
```

If you class doesn't directly extend `Mage_Checkout_CartController`, but is still an instance of it, then you can directly access it this way:

```
Mage_Checkout_CartController::addAction();
```

Comment: Thanks Joe, how would I go about using $this in combination with that? Doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: There's no need to use `$this`. Just replace `$this->addAction()` with one of the examples in my answer.